# Problems with two 2D arrays, not iterating correctly

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have two 2D arrays for a class called quiz. My logic of manipulating these arrays is not correct as i'm not getting the corrected output i expected. I would appreciate if someone can check my logic and help me figure out what i'm doing wrong:

Here are my arrays:

```
public String [][] questions ={
        {"L1Q1","L1Q2","L1Q3"},
        {"L2Q1","L2Q2","L2Q3"},
        {"L3Q1","L3Q2","L3Q3"},
        {"L4Q1","L4Q2","L4Q3"},
        {"L5Q1","L5Q2","L5Q3"}};

public String [][] answers = {
        {"A1Q1","A1Q2","A1Q3"},
        {"A2Q1","A2Q2","A2Q3"},
        {"A3Q1","A3Q2","A3Q3"},
        {"A4Q1","A4Q2","A4Q3"},
        {"A5Q1","A5Q2","A5Q3"}};
```

I also have two variables, one called numQuestion, and numQuiz. and I'm passing these two as indexes to the questions array. I'm also using these two indexes to in the answers array. I want to compare if the answer at the specific cell of the 2d array corresponds to the correct answer of the question. Here is a snipped of my code that i wrote to do that:

```
    public void review(String answer) {
         int y = questionNum;
         int x = quizVal;
        if( answer.equals(answers[x][y])){ 
            currentQuestionCorrect = true;
        } else {
            currentQuestionCorrect= false;
        }

    }//end of review
```

my program is running and it's working, but the review method keeps saying that my answers are wrong when they are correct. can someone please help me

Comment: What are your values for x and y? And also what is your answer for given x,y?  We need an example to be able to help.

Comment: how are you setting x and y?

Comment: thank you for offering to help. "y" is initially zero, and because this is a GUI i'm incrementing "y" each time the user submits an answer to the first question and wants to see the next question. "x" is the value of which quiz the user wants to see, i.e. quiz 1, 2, etc.

Comment: Each row in both arrays is a quiz. and each column of the first array is a question. each column of the second array is an answer.  L1Q1 has the answer A1Q1 and L1Q2 has the answer A1Q2. etc etc. and L5Q3 is the answer to L5Q3

Comment: @Farah Are you subtracting 1 from the user selection of x? Which would give the appropriate index for location in the array?

Comment: Post more code please and eventually some outputs. Also what says the debugger about `answer`and `x`,`y`values ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post all relevant info so we don't have to guess. Best is [mcve] or at least the essential values : `answer, questionNum, quizVal`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that when you click on first line you set x to 0 and not to 1 ? Idem for column.

Comment: i tried that but i continue to get wrong output. and the wrong output are random so i can't exactly tell a pattern

Comment: When you click on the first row, how do you set x and y ? What answer do you make ? What reply do you get ? It is difficult from your post to figure out how you want to make your UI work.